# So, what will happen with Community Wiki by owner?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-wiki

I have seen several discussions on this subject but I don't retrieve them.
Will it, when the dust settles down, be possible on MO2.0 for someone asking a question, or posting an answer, to make it community wiki ? Right now it doesn't seem to be possible, and I think it is a really bad change from the old version.
(otherwise I like the new version pretty much, but this issue worries me)

Comment: I've seen the (irreversible!) community wiki option misused so often, I think it's a good idea to have an approval mechanism.

Answer (score 5):

When posting a question one cannot make it into a community wiki question. That will have to go through flagging your own question and requesting the moderators to do so.

Seeing how the volume of CW questions shouldn't be *that* large, that's probably fine.

When posting an answer, however, there is a checkbox at the bottom right part of the answer box which allows you to make it into a community wiki answer. That's still available for everyone.

It should be noted that now moderators can reverse community wiki status, for example if someone is updating their question and accidentally stepped into the amount of edits which trigger automatic CW.

Comment: Ah okay. I have mixed feelings with that at best. For one thing I didn't think that the number of CW questions was too large. A technical question: I assume that when your question is made CW by the moderators,

Comment: argh argh argh quel horreur

Comment: You can edit comments, don't worry!

Comment: The new comment system posts your comment each time you type return ???!!!??? No!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yes, no more multiline comments. It's fine, though, you can used to this pretty fast.

Comment: Alas, the system is very keen on shortcuts: enter to post, escape to cancel.  There were some Greasemonkey scripts to override this, but the code seems to have changed and they no longer seem to work.

Comment: Ah okay. But that's a second feature I don't like in the new version. When I think of it, the invasion of Facebook, tweeter, etc. in any question is a third.

Comment: @Joël: The social nets invasion was **much** worse at first. It took some time before they hid everything into the "share" button.

Comment: I
think
you
can
still
make
multi-line
comments
if
you
hold
shift
when
you
press
enter/return.
Edit: Apparently not.

Comment: @Evans: You$${}$$can use$${}$$LaTeX trickery, though!$$\\\phantom{blablablablablabla}\text{- Asaf.}$$

Comment: Sneaky! $\hphantom{Really sneaky!}$